Embedding an exe file into the application in C++
It maybe seems like a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything on the internet. I can't figure out how to embed an executable into the program. The goal is to only have one executable file after compilation but the other one embedded. So that I can extract the file/binary later.
I tried to embed it as a resource but it always results in the error code 1813 when I try to locate it. This is my code:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* resourceName = L"embed.exe";
    HRSRC resourceHandle = FindResourceW(NULL, resourceName, RT_RCDATA);
    if (resourceHandle == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Resource not found! Error code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Resource found!" << endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

I once got it working in a C# project, but I can't remember how I did it. I just added the file and could easily get the stream. Do I have to rely on a .rs-file?
Any help would be appreciated.

Duplicate of how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable, unless I miss something.

Are you actually using the name "embed.exe" in your resource file? Also, what does error code 8013 equate to? and finally, what exactly are you trying to achieve. It is possible to insert an executable by the LoadLibraryEx function.

Did you try using MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID) instead of resourceName (ID is the numeric resource identifier)? If that doesn't work out either, could you pls show the related section of the .rc file where the resource is declared.

@OldBoy error 1813 (not 8013) is ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND

@Holzhax Using a resource is the correct solution. If you are having trouble with it, then you likely did not setup the resource correctly. What does your .rc file actually look like?

@RemyLebeau Thank you, no idea how I got those numbers mixed up.

Error Code 1813 basically means that the resource can't be found. Yeah I think I setup the resource file wrong. When I try to open the resource file it only takes me to the "Resource view" windows. There I can add the executable with import, then I have to type in a "Resource type". Would this be the standard resource type "RT_RCDATA"? Or the file extension? I tried everything but nothing seems to work

Excuse me, the .rc file says
IDR_RT_RCDATA1          RT_RCDATA               "C:\Users\"My Name"\Desktop\embed\x64\Release\embed.exe"

Thank you for your help, I got it working now! MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID) helped

@Holzhax Glad to see you've solved the problem. If my answer is what you want, please accept it. Thank you for your contribution to the stackoverflow community.

You need to use MAKEINTRESOURCE to converts an integer value to a resource type compatible with the resource-management functions. Like this:
HRSRC hRes; 
HMODULE hExe; 
#define IDD 103
hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT("embed.exe"));
if (hExe == NULL)
{
    ......
    return;
}
hRes = FindResource(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD), RT_RCDATA);
if (hRes == NULL)
{
    ......
    return;
}

IDD needs to be declared correctly in the .rc file.
More details please refer to Using Resources.

The OP is using a resource name, not an ID. You don't need to use MAKEINTRESOURCE() if you already have a string. "IDD needs to be declared correctly in the .rc file." - That's also wrong. It needs to be available in the .rc and consuming source code. The standard solution is to define the constant in a header file that gets included in either.

@IInspectable Op've already used MAKEINTRESOURCE and worked. If you have better answer please make one.

Using MAKEINTRESOURCE() solves a problem that is distinctly different from the code in the question. If the question contained a [mcve] I would provide an answer. While it doesn't all I can do is cast a vote to have it closed.
